# Goto not working correctly in batch?

Tags: batch-file

I have a few things set up in a batch game. Instead of going where it is supposed to when the sure enters an option and hits "Enter" it goes to the next thing that starts with a : (I don't know what it is called).

Instead of it going to "Youtube" when the user types "Y".

```
:visitoption
echo Would you like to visit the RST Garry's mod gaming community website?
set /p option=Y or N:
if %option%==Y start chrome (Censored link)
if %option%==N cls goto :youtube
if %option%==y start chrome (Censored link)
if %option%==n cls goto :youtube

:version
cls
@echo off
echo.
echo[ 
@echo off
echo.
echo[ 
echo                               --Version--
echo                               Lightup Demo
@echo off
echo.
echo[ 
@echo off
echo.
echo[ 
@echo off
echo.
echo[ 
pause
goto :versionwhite

:youtube
echo Would you like to visit the Creator's Youtube channel?
echo Gameplay commentarys and such.
set /p option=Y or N:
if %option%==Y start chrome (Censored link)
if %option%==N goto :Beginning
if %option%==y start chrome (Censored link)
if %option%==n goto :Beginning
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially you were missing a command separator after the CLS but I've made some other changes such as `/i` case insensitive comparing and made the checking routines more robust to spaces or no input.

```
:visitoption
echo Would you like to visit the RST Garry's mod gaming community website?
set /p option=Y or N:
if /i "%option%"=="Y" start "" chrome "(Censored link)"
if /i "%option%"=="N" cls & goto :youtube
goto :visitoption
```

Answer (score 0):

The "thing" is called a `label`

Since you have no control over what the user types, you should use

```
if "%option%"=="Y" start chrome (Censored link)
```

that is, quote both sides of the comparison (this is not bullet-proof, but serves adequately where the user is not deliberately trying to break your system.)

Adding the `/i` switch to the `if` will make the comparison case-insensitive.

```
if defined option set "option=%option:~0,1%"
```

will set `option` to just the first character.

Note that if the user replies simply <kbd>Enter</kbd> then the value of the variable remains unchanged. You can use this characteristic to your advantage

```
set "option=defaultvalue"
set /p option=Y or N:
```

will set option to `defaultvalue` if the user replies simply <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

`start` will start a process independently. The batch simply carries on to the next statement. You are probably beter off using `start "window title for this instance" ...` - it's a quirk of `start` that the first `"quoted parameter"` is used as the window title where you may be expecting it to be used as a parameter.

To concatenate a series of commands in a single line, you need to separate the individual commands with an ampersand <kbd>&</kbd>

Once you've turned `echo` off once, you don't need to do it again (unless you execute `echo on`, which you can do during debugging to show the program flow.) The leading <kbd>@</kbd> means `don't echo this command` - without it, the initial `ECHO OFF` would be reproduced.

You can use `call :label` to execute a subroutine that starts at `:label` **in this batch file**. If you use `call label` then the "subroutine" executed is the executable `label`. This is a very important distinction.

For this reason, I eschew the use of `goto :label` - although it works - because the colon is not necessary and for congruence between the `goto` and `call` commands.

The one exception to this omit-the-colons approach is where the colon actually **does** have an effect - goto **<kbd>:</kbd>**eof very specifically means 'goto the physical end of this batch file' - the label `:eof` is understood by `cmd` to have that meaning, and should not be defined in the batch.

Answer (score -1):

You've set it so that it goes to youtube when the user presses `n`, not when the user enters `y` like you said your trying to in the question:

```
if %option%==N cls goto :youtube
```

Please try seeing what the cod eyour using is doing before you post a question on it.

And SO has one of the worlds easiest CodeSlabing systems. HOW BLOODY HARD IS IT TO PRESS SPACE 4 TIMES OR HIGHLIGHT AND PRESS THE `"Code Sample"` BUTTON?

Mona.